# In PHP, how to sort associative array sorting based on key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've a nested associative array like the one below and need help sorting the array for each of the keys such as 'first_name' and 'score'.

For example:

```
Array
(
    [12345] => Array
        (
            [75] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Xen
                    [score] => 245
                )
        )

    [9876] => Array
        (
            [75] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Shane
                    [score] => 300
                )
        ) 
    [4567] => Array
        (
            [75] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Dan
                    [score] => 100
                )
        ) 
)
```

The result should have the array sorted by the keys in ascending order:

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Array
                 (
                   [0] => 4567
                   [1] => 9876
                   [2] => 12345
                 )

    [score] => Array
           (
             [0] => 4567
             [1] => 12345
             [2] => 9876
           )
)
```

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: There a few bajillion q/a's on this site on how to sort arrays in any way imaginable... take a few minutes to look around.

Comment: @Orangepill user1971065 is your mother?

Comment: No my mother is user1723658 :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry, easy mistake to make :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) is PHP's function to sort by key. So to sort an array `$arr` by its keys, do:

```
ksort($arr);
```

Note that `ksort` returns a boolean (success or failure), so you shouldn't do `$arr = ksort($arr);`. `ksort` modifies the original array.

To sort a multidimensional associative array (say, an associative array of associative arrays) recursively by keys, try the user-provided function at the bottom of the `ksort` manual page (I haven't tried this, but it looks like it will work just fine):

```
function deep_ksort(&$arr) {
    ksort($arr);
    foreach ($arr as &$a) {
        if (is_array($a) && !empty($a)) {
            deep_ksort($a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.. will try to use this on more than one key.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php#98465 also seems like a possible solution.